# Absolute value Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a MPL (multiple price list.) on otree (using PyCharm).
For one of my app (WTP) I wrote this code on the html "folder" (using Javascript):

```
{% if choice.0 > 0 %}  If you are paid {{choice.0}} points for this item, would you accept?
    {% elif choice.0 == 0 %}
        If you are paid {{choice.0}} points for this item, would you accept?
    {% elif choice.0 < 0 %}
        If you have to pay {{choice.0}} points for this item, would you accept?
    {% endif %}
```

the different choices being defined on pages.py:

```
  self.participant.vars['choices'] = [
        [+30, "choice1", "choice1-yes", "choice1-no"],
        [+20, "choice2", "choice2-yes", "choice2-no"],
        [+10, "choice3", "choice3-yes", "choice3-no"],
        [0, "choice4", "choice4-yes", "choice4-no"],
        [-10, "choice5", "choice5-yes", "choice5-no"],
        [-20, "choice6", "choice6-yes", "choice6-no"],
        [-30, "choice7", "choice7-yes", "choice7-no"],
```

However, I would like all the numbers to appear without the "minus" sign on the participants' screen. How can I modify my Javascript code s.t. -10 becomes 10, -20 becomes 20 and -30 becomes 30.

Thanks!

Comment: Math.abs(-20) maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Math.abs()`:

```
Math.abs(-30) // 30
```

Edit: It seems that your syntax is of django templates but you ask about javasscript. if thats the case use [django mathfilters](http://pypi.org/project/django-mathfilters/0.1.2)

Comment: I tried to insert {{Math.abs(choice.0)}} and also {{Math.abs("choice.0")}} on the html page but this does not work (I would like to change directly in the html interface and not on my pages.py if that is possible)

Comment: @Bénédicte it seems that your syntax is of django templates but you ask about javasscript. if thats the case use https://pypi.org/project/django-mathfilters/0.1.2/

Comment: You're right! Thanks for the comment. I tried to put {{choice.0|abs}} but I still get this response : TemplateSyntaxError: Unrecognised filter name 'abs' (line 54, in "choice.0|abs"). Maybe I am missing something: I typed $ pip install django-mathfilters
into my command but how can I add mathfilters to my INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: did you use {% load mathfilters %} at the top of the file?

Comment: yes.. I used {% load otree static %} and {% load mathfilters %} at the top of the file :( (I am using PyCharm btw and am on the app "templates"). I don't know if this makes a difference.